# How to change margins in documentclass thesis

Tags: margins, document-classes, geometry, thesis

I am using a template for my thesis and I would like to change the margins. Actually, I'm satisfied with all the margins, except the top margin which is too tight. But when I try to use `geometry` package, everything is corrupted and the text starts from the toppest part of the page (maybe I can call it a 0 cm margin). I think the reason is that I have a headline at the top of each page which includes the title of the chapter. Could you please help me with my problems?

In case you need, I have the following line in my main.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{Thesis} % The default font size and one-sided printing (no margin offsets)
```

I'm actually totally new to Latex, but I assume that what is interesting to you in the thesis.cls file is the following:

```
\setmarginsrb  { 1.5in}  % left margin
                    { 0.6in}  % top margin
                    { 1.0in}  % right margin
                    { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                    {  20pt}  % head height
                    {0.25in}  % head sep
                    {   9pt}  % foot height
                    { 0.3in}  % foot sep
```

If I still have not provided enough information, may I kindly ask you to download the template from [Here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)? The template sounds complicated to me and I don't know which parts to keep and which parts to leave out.

Comment: There is a whole bunch of classes  that are called ‘Thesis’. Where did you get it from?

Comment: Please provide the actual documentclass file (or its location) along with a complete, but minimal(!!) `.tex` file that others can test.

Comment: Dear @jon and Dear Berard, 
Thanks a lot for your helps. I tried to complete my question. Could you please take another look at that? Thanks.

Comment: Not quite useful enough, I'm afraid: for `.tex` files, we really need complete (but minimal) files. Please read about [minimal examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: The class uses the package `vmargin` that I can't recommend; so you can't load also `geometry`, because the two packages fight with one another.

Comment: The template you linked does not use that hacky approach, hence there is no need to fiddle with anything.

Comment: Not an answer, but a suggestion to help you visualize what's happening, you could use the package `showframe` wich will show you the place and size of the margin and headline and footline.

Comment: I actually changed the margin in the thesis.cls manually and it solved my problem. Have I done the stupidest thing I could have done?

Answer (score 1):

The template does not use package `vmargin` in its current form. It uses package `geometry` and you can change the margins using `\geometry{margin=1in}`.

Answer (score 0):

Without posting a minimal example, it is difficult to help you achieve what you want in the most ideal way possible.

Without knowing how your thesis.sty file looks, I could suggest that you alter the top margin manually by adjusting the vertical offset from the top of the page `\voffset` TeX primitive.

```
% Syntax: \voffset=⟨dimen⟩

\setlength{\voffset}{-5cm}
```

The value can be positive or negative. Keep in mind that the default value is probably set within the thesis.sty file (that you did not post)